# How to create intersection data in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, set-intersection

I have a problem that I need to solve which is somewhat simplistic but I can't work it out. Any help is much appreciated.

ok. I have a dataset of a million records:

```
TransId, PersonGUID, Origin.
```

Origin has 2 options: [Credit, Current]

Now, I need to filter down to only those transactions where a PersonGUID has had both at least 1 row in Credit and Current.

I can do this somewhat easily in PythonPandas and load in the CSV but I don't want 2 datasets as I'll be building a dashboard around ALL data.

I am guessing a boolean logic calculated field but I can't work it out.

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a conditional filter.

Drag PersonGUID to filter, and choose the tab Condition. Select Formula and insert some formula that will give the result you want. Probably something like:

```
SUM(
IF Origin = 'Credit'   THEN  1    ELSE 0    END
) > 0
AND
SUM(
IF Origin = 'Current'    THEN  1    ELSE 0    END
) > 0
```

The first sum will be 0 if there's no 'Credit' for the user, and >0 otherwise. Same logic to the second.

This way, this calculation will be made to each PersonGUID, and you'll achieve what you need

Comment: Doesn't work sorry. No differentiation only False
I managed to find a solution by by creating a set of exclusions that didn't kill Tableau.

Comment: I'm gonna need a little bit more than "doesn't work" to help you. Is it filtering too much? Not filtering enough? Not filtering at all?

Comment: I hit return before completing editing. I am really interested in knowing how to do this for large datasets. I understand the concept but it doesn't seem to work i.e. any true answers

Comment: Man, just run on dummy data and it worked perfectly. Is your [Origin] field of type string?  Are the values actually 'Credit' and 'Current'? Did you use the condition filter (and it is important that you don't filter anything on General and Wildcard) and pasted exactly my formula?

Comment: Its late and I didn't check my data correctly. Just changed the labels of Origin to CreditCard/CurrentAccount a and voila. Thanks!

Comment: Haha! Been there, done that. Glad it worked, and hope you learned something to be used in the future =D

Comment: Inox gave you good advice. A couple of other tips. First, you don't really have to say "ELSE 0". If you don't provide an else, the formula will evaluate to null when the if condition is not satisfied. Null values are ignored by aggregation functions like Sum. Second, if you drop the else clause, you can then replace SUM() by COUNT() which a good database query optimizer can exploit to be a little more efficient.