# Tableau: Selecting attribute levels and get and intersection instead of a union

Tags: tableau-api

I'm having some texts and for each text I'm having some tokens attached to it in a single column. The data looks like

```
Text_ID, Token
1, energy
1, debit
1, flat
2, energy
2, house
3, energy
3, debit
```

I created a metric according to `countd(Text_ID)` to count the numbers of distinct texts/text_ids. Now putting everything in the obvious way on a worksheet and selecting/filtering some tokens gives me essentially a union.

I'd like to select energy and debit and get the proper count 2 instead of 3 here. Of course I'm having a lot of tokens, hence the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929313/how-to-create-intersection-data-in-tableau) is not scalable.

Any suggestions on how to proceed here?
I'd assume that I need to create two parameters here, but I don't know how to use them to filter properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to identify the Text Ids that have at least one data row containing one specified token, “energy” in your example, and also have at least one data row containing another specified token, “debt” in your example. If that is the problem then I’d suggest using a set as follows.

1. Define two parameters to allow users to specify their tokens of interest, called for instance, token_1 and token_2
2. Define a set based on the Text Id field called Selected_Texts using the condition `MAX([Token] = token_1) and MAX([Token] = token_2)`

You can use the set in many different ways. If you want to count the number of distinct text ids that are in the set, create a calculated field called Selected_Text_Id as `if [Selected_Texts] then [Text_ID] end` Which holds the text id for matching texts and is null for others. Then you can plot COUNTD([Selected_Text_Id]) to answer your original question.

Comment: Thanks, this also seems to mitigate the issue with `Param1 = Param2` described above in my comment on Siva's answer. I'll investigate that later, though.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 paramter fields for selecting the required values and create a formula and add below code:

```
{ FIXED  [Text ID]:
SUM(IF [Token] = [Parameter 1]
or [Token] = [Parameter 2]
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END)}
```

Comment: is the `or` right or should it be an `and`. This approach also scales to 3 or more Combinations, which is nice. What is the comma after Text ID meaning?

Comment: apologize, you can remove `,` and it should be `or` because you need to loop through rows

Comment: So your suggestion is then, to create a filter from this metric that only "fires" if the sum (per text_ID) is two (or the count of parameters), right? However, this approach has the disadvantage of necessarily selecting two different "tokens" in my example. I mean I could add an `if Param 1 = Param 2 then 2` here. Any comments on this?

Comment: sorry didn't get you if you create 2 parameters then 2 different tokens will be selected and also your field in database is holding a single token, if it holds multiple tokens then there is a different way, basically how data is stored in database will decide the formula